# Hello, I keep getting undefined when I run this piece of code

Tags: javascript

this is my code:

```
  var a = 10;


for(var i = 0; i < a; i++){   document.write(a[i]); }
```

I have left the var empty but it still didn't work.

Comment: oh i see now, thank you for pointing that out, i was getting array and loops confused but this code works now. var a = 10; for(var i = 0; i < a; i++){
  document.write(i + "</br>");
}

Answer (score 1):

`a[i]` looks up the property whose name is the value of `i` on whatever's in `a`. What you have in `a` is the primitive number `10`. When you try to get an object property from a primitive number, it gets temporarily promoted to the equivalent `Number` instance, and then the property is taken from that instance. *(Loosely speaking.)*

Your `i` has the vaules `0` through `9`, so those are the names of the properties that get looked up. Numbers don't have properties with those names, and so you get what you always get when you try to retrieve a property that doesn't exist: `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You attempt to subscript an integer variable is not going to work. Try using an array instead.

```
var a = [item1, item2, ...];
```

and then use a loop to iterate over individual item and display:

```
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {   
document.write(a[i]); 
}
```